# How to get square crop hint from Google Cloud Vision?

Tags: java, google-cloud-vision

How to get square crop hint from Google Cloud Vision?

I'm setting the aspect ratio to 1 but the resulting hint is never an exact square.

Below is the modified example from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-crop-hints checking sample image from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/images/cat.jpg.

```java
public class QuickTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "/path/to/cat.jpg";
        List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.readFrom(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
        CropHintsParams cropHintsParams = CropHintsParams.newBuilder().clearAspectRatios().addAspectRatios(1).build();
        Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Feature.Type.CROP_HINTS).build();
        AnnotateImageRequest request =
                AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img)
                        .setImageContext(ImageContext.newBuilder().setCropHintsParams(cropHintsParams).build())
                        .build();
        requests.add(request);
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response =
                ImageAnnotatorClient.create().batchAnnotateImages(requests);
        List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();
        for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
            if (res.hasError()) {
                System.out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
                return;
            }
            CropHintsAnnotation annotation = res.getCropHintsAnnotation();
            for (CropHint hint : annotation.getCropHintsList()) {
                System.out.println(hint.getBoundingPoly());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is (zeroes are not printed):

```
vertices {
}
vertices {
  x: 1100
}
vertices {
  x: 1100
  y: 1114
}
vertices {
  y: 1114
}
```

Comment: any solution..?

Comment: Its returning max width & height of bitmap